# Error updating Django

Tags: python, django

I get the following error when I type "pip install -U Django":

```
Collecting Django   Using cached Django-2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/tn/d7vg_zcd5pq0cq3sltw0j7pc0000gn/T/pip-build-xIsFov/Django/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
        version = __import__('django').get_version()
      File "django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.utils.version import get_version
      File "django/utils/version.py", line 61, in <module>
        @functools.lru_cache()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

    ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/tn/d7vg_zcd5pq0cq3sltw0j7pc0000gn/T/pip-build-xIsFov/Django/
```

I read that this relates to the version of python. But if I type python3 in terminal I get :

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

Comment: You probably install it on `pip` for Python-2.x, what happens if you do `pip3 install -U Django`?

Comment: That worked. Thank you!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you should probably post your comment as an answer and Dan should close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has to do with:

```
@functools.lru_cache()
```

The `functools` if [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) has no `lru_cache` decorator, indeed:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Nov 23 2017, 15:37:09) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import functools
>>> functools.lru_cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'
>>> 
$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Nov 23 2017, 11:34:05) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import functools
>>> functools.lru_cache
<function lru_cache at 0x7f23e3e8b378>
```

So that means that you aimed to install [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0) in a [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) environment, which is [*not* supported](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#python-compatibility).

If you plan to use it globally with [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), you need to use a package manager for [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), which is for instance `pip3` (not `pip`). So you can install it with:

```
pip3 install -U Django
```